# Removing in app purchases from a new version of the application(iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, version

I have an application that is live on iTunes. The app contains lots of in app purchases(non consummable). I wish to delete supoort for some in app purchases from the new version. Can I do it ? Will it lead to rejection because the user wont be able to restore those in app purchases? What would be the best way to go about it ?

Comment: Just go to **itunes connect** and **delete** it from the **in-app purchases module** in your app

Comment: The in app is approved and I am not getting an option to delete it. Can I delete approved in apps?

Answer (score 45):

From the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW19), you need to first set the "Cleared for sale" to NO, then delete the product.

> Deleting In-App Purchases You can delete in-app purchases after they
>   are created, but not if they are in review. Before you delete an
>   approved in-app purchase, you should first remove it from sale.
>
> Important: After you delete an in-app purchase, it is no longer
>   searchable on iTunes Connect and it cannot be restored. The product ID
>   for the in-app purchase can no longer be used for another in-app
>   purchase after the in-app purchase is deleted.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Don't know why deleting an app is not easy that way? :)

Comment: but what about my previous version support. it will be there till my new app is in review or not?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, it is possible to delete an in-app purchase while it is in Approved state.

1 - Log in to iTunes Connect & navigate to "Manage Your Apps section"; chose your app in there.

2- Navigate to "Manage In-App Purchases"

3- Now you need to mark the approved in-app purchased to "NOT clear for sale". Click the first "Edit" button that lets you change the summary/details of the in-app purchase. A new form/page will open. Search for "Clear For Sale" option and select "No" against it. Save your change.

4- A "delete" button will now appear at the top left corner of in-app details page. Just click that button and the in-app will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for telling me where the Delete button appears. I was following the other answers and was going nuts because I couldn't find it.

Comment: Option will appear after you add least add one localization and untick cleared for sale. Small red dot appear when you scroll over in-app purchase, so you can click to delete.