# Want to remove IAP from released app

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to remove an in app purchase from my itunesconnect, but the delete button is grayed out. Anyone know if it's possible to delete the IAP option from an already-released app?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find / work anything out for this? What did you do in the end?

Comment: I think my question was as much about whether the app would be "stable" without an in app purchase associated with it, since it was still marked as using them. I deleted the IAP and no problems ensued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Removing in app purchases from a new version of the application(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392492/removing-in-app-purchases-from-a-new-version-of-the-applicationios).

I've pasted the accepted answer for that question below for convenience. Sorry if that's not good SO practice - please let me know.

---

From the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW19), you need to first set the "Cleared for sale" to NO, then delete the product.

> Deleting In-App Purchases You can delete in-app purchases after they
>   are created, but not if they are in review. Before you delete an
>   approved in-app purchase, you should first remove it from sale.
>
> Important: After you delete an in-app purchase, it is no longer
>   searchable on iTunes Connect and it cannot be restored. The product ID
>   for the in-app purchase can no longer be used for another in-app
>   purchase after the in-app purchase is deleted.