# iOS: delete IAP receipt programmatically

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm testing auto-renewable subscription and I have the following problem:

1. I make a purchase on device A
2. With the same AppleID I restore the receipt on device B
3. I change AppleID (from device settings) on device B
4. I still have the receipt on device B that makes me a paying user

In this way a purchase can be duplicated just logging-in one time with a paying AppleID. So, how can I delete a receipt from a device? Or tell me if there's another solution...

Comment: no public api to check logged in user apple id - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009530/is-it-possible-to-get-the-users-apple-id-through-the-sdk

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the receipt with SKReceiptRefreshRequest https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKReceiptRefreshRequest_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Receipt_Properties

Comment: @MarcGreenstock refreshing the receipt opens a login dialog and it's quite disturbing for UX, especially if I have to do this often

Comment: Do you got solution of the problem?

Comment: @RajenderKumar unfortunately no, I didn't find any solution

Comment: You can try other ways like [Removing in app purchases from a new version of the application(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392492/6521116)